# Calculate sums within a view for certain lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, denodo

i have the following problem:

i have a view, which contains a id, a month_date, a max_month_date and a balance. I would now like to do a self join, where the id is compared with the id and the max_month_date is compared to the month_date. Thus only the lines with the maximum month_date should be written to a new view.
That is the starting point:

```
id     month_date    max_month_date     balance 
1      2020-01-12    2020-01-31         100
1      2020-01-16    2020-01-31         150
1      2020-01-31    2020-01-31         200
1      2020-02-03    2020-02-23         100
1      2020-02-23    2020-02-23         150
1      2020-02-23    2020-02-23         -150
```

My join therefore is:

```
SELECT t.main_id,
   t.month_date,
   t.max_month_date,
   t.balance
FROM test_view t
INNER JOIN test_view s 
ON t.main_id = s.main_id
AND t.month_date = s.max_month_date
```

The problem is that there are lines that have the same id and the same max_month_date. The balance is different. For this reason too many lines have been written in the ouput.

From a theoretical point of view, I would have to add up all balances that have the same id and the same max_month_date.
In the above case, this applies to the last two lines:

```
    id     month_date    max_month_date     balance
    1      2020-02-23    2020-02-23         0
```

Then the duplicate data records would have to be removed in the main view and only filled with the lines that make up the total of the balances.
Like this:

```
    id     month_date    max_month_date     balance
    1      2020-01-12    2020-01-31         100
    1      2020-01-16    2020-01-31         150
    1      2020-01-31    2020-01-31         200
    1      2020-02-03    2020-02-23         100
    1      2020-02-23    2020-02-23         0
```

Does anyone have an idea and can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the problem is the duplicates of the View but you did not post the code of the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.`COUNT` window function makes sure grouping same values together regardless of negative or possitive. Then if that counts >1 sum `BALANCE` column grouping BY `MAIN_ID,MONTH_DATE,MAX_MONTH_DATE` else `BALANCE`.

[Working Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a976887f5165be635853358f7b5a021a)

[image]

```
WITH TEST_VIEW AS (
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-12',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-31',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         100  AS balance  UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-16',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-31',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         150  AS balance  UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-31',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-01-31',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         200  AS balance  UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-03',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-23',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         100  AS balance  UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-23',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-23',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         150  AS balance  UNION ALL
SELECT 1 MAIN_ID,     CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-23',102) AS MONTH_DATE,    CONVERT(DATETIME,'2020-02-23',102) AS MAX_MONTH_DATE,         -150 AS balance  
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       T.MAIN_ID,
       T.MONTH_DATE,
       T.MAX_MONTH_DATE,
       CASE
          WHEN BALC > 1
          THEN
             SUM (BALANCE)
                OVER (PARTITION BY T.MAIN_ID, T.MONTH_DATE, T.MAX_MONTH_DATE)
          ELSE
             BALANCE
       END
          SUMM
  FROM (SELECT T.MAIN_ID,
               T.MONTH_DATE,
               T.MAX_MONTH_DATE,
               T.BALANCE,
               COUNT (*)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY T.MAIN_ID,
                                     T.MONTH_DATE,
                                     T.MAX_MONTH_DATE,
                                     ABS (T.BALANCE))
                  BALC
          FROM TEST_VIEW T) T
```

Comment: Hey adding works now. But unfortunately he now does it for all the other lines too ...

Comment: Which query do you mean? First or second ? @G21

Comment: the first one. The concept is great and it filters all rows perfect. but the other rows are also cumulated now, although they shouldn't

Comment: Try last one. @G21

Comment: yeah thanks! The problem ist that the table has more than  4 Million Rows. It's just a test table below. How to make that function for the whole table ? i cant convert every row... do u have a idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219671/discussion-between-ismetguzelgun-and-g21).

Answer (score 0):

try using SQL DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.main_id,
t.month_date,
t.max_month_date,
t.balance
FROM test_view t
INNER JOIN test_view s 
ON t.main_id = s.main_id
AND t.month_date = s.max_month_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.main_id, t.month_date, t.max_month_date,  t.balance
FROM test_view t
WHERE t.month_date = t.max_month_date;
```

No `JOIN` is necessary.

If the view doesn't have the `max_month_date`, then you can use window functions to calculate it:

```
SELECT t.main_id, t.month_date, t.max_month_date,  t.balance
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(month_date) OVER (PARTITION BY main_id) as max_month_date
      FROM test_view t
     ) t
WHERE t.month_date = t.max_month_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, it is important that the last values, i.e. -100 and 100 in my case, are added to 0. This must apply to all lines that have the same Max_Datumm, the same month date and the same ID

Comment: @G21 . . . Your question is:  "Thus only the lines with the maximum month_date should be written to a new view. "  If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question with a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.